# how to bring back value of the variable that was set in child cmd prompt?

Tags: batch-file, scope

In this example the result is that the rest of the script doesn't see that the variable was changed.

```
set testvar=initial_value
start "" /b /belownormal /wait cmd /c set testvar=im'changed
echo %testvar%
```

Is there any way to bring back it's value back to main command prompt ?
(this is simplified example of an app that I must run in lower cpu priority, and then I need to receive it's errorlevel value by using `&&` like this:

```
start "" /b /belownormal /wait cmd /c myapp.exe  && set elevel=ok || set elevel=fail
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
set testvar=initial_value
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('start "" /b /belownormal /wait cmd /c echo(im^'changed') do SET "testvar=%%a"
echo %testvar%
```

.. or with `errorlevel`:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
start "" /b /belownormal /wait cmd /c EXIT /b 322
echo %errorlevel%
```